# RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync causes app to exit without exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

And working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app, and I wish to render some xaml to an image file.

From [this page on the RenderTargetBitmap class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx), it appears that my xaml must be connected to the visual tree, so I inserted the element off-screen.
Just above the examples section, it states that

> •Content that's in the XAML visual tree but offscreen can be captured, so long as it's not Visibility=Collapsed or in the other restricted cases.

So I would think I'd be good to go... except that executing the RenderAsync method causes my app to exit without triggering any exceptions.

edit: I tried wrapping my code like this:

```
    try
    {
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(LiveTileSource);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
```

By placing breakpoints on the lines beginning with await and throw, I can see in my app that execution gets to the RenderAsync call. The app then reliably exits without catching any exceptions.

Comment: Are all exceptions turned on. I know that by default Visual Studio does not stop on every exception.

Comment: Yes, they are.

I also tried wrapping that one line in a try block... I'll update my post to show this.

Comment: Does `LiveTileSource` derive `UIElement` or something else?

Comment: Nothing in the output window?

Comment: Is 'Just My Code' enabled? If it is disable it and you should at least get the app to stop.

Comment: Interestingly, I am seeing the same thing when the content is off screen, But it works fine when the content is on screen.

Comment: LiveTileSource is a StackPanel. I gave it name so I could reference it in the code-behind.

Comment: If I'm not the only one seeing this problem, then it's probably an error in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, it was failing silently with Access Violation in the Output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discrepancy in the MSDN documentation between [the RenderTargetBitmap page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) and [the RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298556.aspx).

On the first page:

> •Content that's in the XAML visual tree but offscreen can be captured

On the second page:

> •Content that's in the XAML visual tree but offscreen won't be captured

It appears to fail silently with an Access Violation.

Comment: Is there any wait to catch such Exception in the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer would be relevant, but it seems like you can put your `LiveTileSource` inside a Canvas, place it off-screen, and this will work. Here is a sample code I use for testing right now:

```
var tileCanvas = new Canvas();
Canvas.SetLeft(LiveTileSource, Window.Current.Bounds.Right);
Canvas.SetTop(LiveTileSource, Window.Current.Bounds.Bottom);
tileCanvas.Children.Add(LiveTileSource);
page.Children.Add(tileCanvas);

var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(LiveTileSource);
// ...
page.Children.Remove(tileCanvas);
```

This doesn't seem to throw Access Violation.